# Virtualbox development network using FreeBSD

Tags: networking, virtualbox, scalability

I want to setup virtual network with 3 guest OS(FreeBSD) for testing scalable webapp. The first one should be only MySQL master server. Second and Third will be slaves with read only MySQL's and webservers.

Currently I have installed 3 identical virtual machines. My problem is setting up the network, so 3 guests can see each other and Host OS(Win7) can see webservers.

How I should configure virtualbox network settings? What network configuration I should give in FreeBSD and host OS?

And in general. Is this a good way to do development/testing of distributed webapp on local machine?

**Edit:**
Some progress, but not ideal. problem in details: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=49150

Answer (score 2):

The trouble I see with this is that it's kind of vague. There's more than one way to do it...

Bridge your network connections so each VM looks like a machine on your network; then you'd treat them as just that. Other machines on your network. With their own IP's and visible from other computers alongside your host system.

Or you can set up Virtualbox so it's creating an internal private network so they each see only each other, and other machines on your network can't see them. It isolates your test environment to just your computer/host.

It entirely depends on how you want to actually test them and from what machines. If you bridge them it may make things easier for you with management and allowing other systems to test without modification. Look in the manual for Virtualbox under bridged network connections.

Comment: Actually at this moment I need that network for only my Host OS. So I should go for Internal Network? It's easier to install? Because am new to networking and BSD.

Comment: There's nothing to install really, or there shouldn't be. It's a setting for the VM where you configure the VM's networking "hardware".

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I wrote install instead configure. I am following this guide https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testing_Networks. I have 192.168.56.1 IP assigned to my Host's "VirtualBox Host-Only Network". But when I set that IP as gateway in guest FreeBSD, I get Network is unreachable. See screenshot http://postimage.org/image/dzenzx6tx/